# How do I calculated group averages with a filter in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got data across 2 tables that kind of looks like:

```
Table 1
Mean | Activity   | name_id
---------------------------
1    | Swimming   | 1
3    | Basketball | 2
3    | Swimming   | 3
9    | Running    | 1
5    | Basketball | 3

TypeName | Name_id
------------------
ABC      | 1
DEF      | 2
GHI      | 3
```

Assuming joins are in place, I want to run the equivalent of this SQL:

```
select activity, avg(mean)
from table1 a
inner join table2 
 on table1.name_id = table2.name_id
where table2.name_id = 'DEF'
```

I got a basic quick measure that does everything except for the filter for 'DEF' name_ids:

```
Average = 
AVERAGEX(
    KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Table1'[Activity])),
    CALCULATE(SUM('Table1'[Mean]))
)
```

I'm stumped as to where exactly I should put a filter. I also tried using `CALCULATE` as the base function, but was stumped on how to properly run that.

Comment: I don't understand the SQL join. What would be the expected result?

Comment: I don't see any `ID` values in your tables. How do you relate them?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that those ids in.